# How do I 'wait' for a certain dialogue in a Word document macro?

Tags: vba, ms-word, ms-office, office-2007

I’ve got a macro that does a search/replace in a selection but at the end of the task it shows the 'Do you want to search the remainder of the document' dialogue and I never want it to search the remainder so I’d like to have it click ‘n’ and then continue with the rest of the doc.

In is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsNone
```

edit: More detail on the property here- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa212820(office.11).aspx

Comment: good thought...unfortunately the default value is  'yes' and I need 'no'..80(

Comment: Oops, I totally read right past that (n) part.  What about using an application event?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140279(office.10).aspx  I'm guessing that a dialog box would deactivate the active window?  Then you could sendkey an n maybe?